# Can vscode support absolute path references for ES6 imports?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Instead of relative paths, e.g. `import Foo from '../Foo'`, which can get hairy when you have a larger project, we've started using "absolute" paths, e.g. `import Foo from '~/utils/Foo'`, where `~` is mapped to our root JS directory (say `assets/js` or what not).

This seems to break vscode's control-click navigation and, I suspect, all of the auto-/implicit-inference it does, due to it fundamentally not being able to follow the import statements.

Is there a way to map `~` to a specific folder/sub-folder in vscode, so that this will work again?

(Ideally we could have multiple mappings, e.g. one for our production JS code in `src/main/js` and one for our test JS code, e.g. in `src/test/js`.)

Comment: I'd love to see this, but haven't found a way to do it yet.

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe this is supported for plain JavaScript projects, but it is supported for Typescript projects (and I'll detail a workaround you can use to enable it for JS projects too). I recommend you [open a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) if you would like better support for this sort of functionality.

To enable this in a TypeScript project, create a `tsconfig.json` file in the root of your project:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": [
                "assets/js/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

`paths` is the mapping you want. [Here's more information about mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url).

Now any imports of the form:

```
import Foo from '~/utils/Foo'
```

will be resolved to

```
 import Foo from 'assets/js/utils/Foo'
```

That will only work in TypeScript files by default, but you can also enable it in JS files by adding `"allowJs": true` to the `tsconfig.json` like so:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": [
                "assets/js/*"
            ]
        },
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

This should enable the same intellisense functionality for JavaScript files in your project.

In the JavaScript case, remember that the `paths` configuration is only for tooling support. It will not change the runtime behavior of your code, so you'll still have to ensure your runtime can resolve module paths `'~/utils/Foo'` properly.

Again, please consider opening a feature request against VSCode if you would like this scenario to be better supported or have any ideas on how things could be improved here.